# Getting textbox to turn red on change

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make my textbox red when someone starts adding text to it. The problem I'm having is it takes long
to hit my onChange method and change the text color red.

Here is my code

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            v-model="product.name"
                            @change="onChange"
                            :style="{ color: conditionalColor}"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            props: ['product'],
            computed: {
                conditionalColor(){
                    return this.dirty ? 'red' : ''
                }
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    dirty: false
                }
            },
            methods: {
                onChange(){
                    console.log('changing');
                    return this.dirty = true;
                }
            },
            mounted() {

            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try watching `product.name` and setting `this.dirty = true;` there.  The first time you edit the input after mounting it will fire and accomplish the same as your `onChange` method.  Additionally, you can save some steps by conditionally applying a CSS class instead of computing it.

```js
<template>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" :class="{ 'dirty': dirty }" v-model="product.name">
</template>

<style>
  .dirty { color: red; }
</style>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['product'],
    data() {
      return {
        dirty: false
      }
    },
    watch: {
      'product.name': function() {
        this.dirty = true;
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also alternative way to style your input.

```
 <template>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" :class="{ 'dirty': product.name.length > 0}" v-model="product.name">
    </template>
    
    
    <style>
      .dirty { color: red; }
    </style>
```